# How can I measure ms between frame to reproduce it

Tags: frame-rate

Hello I'm coding a extension to an existing game - not really an extension since a re-code all so the it looks like another adventure for player - and to achieve it I use existing tilesets and so, but my main problem is for animated tilesets, I can't find anywhere the frame rate, sometimes I assumed it was simply 60fps (16.67ms between frame) because I figured out testing that it should be somewhere between 15ms and 20ms, but I have to good way to figure it out, I wanted to use something like OBS in 1000 fps but it doesn't seem available, in any other recording app neither. How would/did you guys do what I need to?
Thanks in advance and gl in your own projects!

EDIT1: I'm trying to find the *intended* frame rate of the animation (that is, how long the author of the animation expected each frame to stay on screen?) ; Because sometimes it's really really short like around 15ms how can I do that? My question is not about global fps but some animated tile fps

Comment: HI axel, could you elaborate on the platform/tech/game you are working in.  This will help with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know where the data that specifies the animation's rate is stored in the game (which would be the best place to extract it from), you'll be forced to use empirical observation to derive the framerate.

You can do this with OBS or other screen recording software, as you posited, and you don't need the game to run at 1000 FPS to do so. Faster would be better, but if you're suspecting that the animation frames have a delay of about 15-20ms, 1000 FPS is overkill. 60 is perfectly fine.

Just record a video of the animations in question and play it back frame by frame, counting how many video frames a given animation frame is active before changing. Multiply that by the frame time of the recording to get the frame time of that animation frame. If your recording is high-fidelity enough and matching the actual game render rate enough, this will give you a reasonable approximation of the animation rate, which you can fine-tune by hand if needed.

Note that if the game alters the framerate for its animations under any circumstances, such as for dramatic effect or simply such that each frame of an animation may stay on screen for its own period of time, your observations will be impacted by that.